# How to change JTextArea when Progress Bar is 100%

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I am very new to Java language and I started to make a program just by myself and the internet. For now I have this :

```
package com.butoane;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class App {
private JButton apasaAiciButton;
private JPanel Dunno;
private JButton apoiaici;
private JTextArea text1;
private JProgressBar progressBar1;
private JTextArea text2;

public App() {
   String a = "H";
   String b = "e";
   String y = "Ce faci sefule??";
    final String[] d = {"x"};
    final String[] f = {"D"};
    final int[] c = {0};
    apasaAiciButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //apoiaici.setEnabled(true);
            //apasaAiciButton.setEnabled(false);
            text1.append(a);
            progressBar1.setValue(c[0] +1);
            c[0] = c[0] +1;
        }

    });
    apoiaici.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //apoiaici.setEnabled(false);
            //apasaAiciButton.setEnabled(true);
            apasaAiciButton.setText("Apasa iar aici");
            text1.append(b);
            progressBar1.setValue(c[0] +1);
            c[0] = c[0] +1;
        }
    });

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
    frame.setContentPane(new App().Dunno);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

What I want to do is to add a functionality to text2 when progress bar is 100%.
For example : When progressbar1 will be 100% , text2 to set the text to "You did it!" . How can I make this?

FYK : I viewed oracle docs about JProgressBar and JTextArea and I could not understand a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the progress bar work?
if it works, then just add.

```
//the max value of the progress bar == actual value
if (progressBar1.getMaximum() == progressBar1.getValue() {
    text2.append("You did it!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will throw NullPointerException since you didn't initialize any widget. Add a listener to your progressbar(Assuming you're using java 8+)

```
progressBar1.addChangeListener(e ->
{
        javax.swing.JProgressBar bar = (javax.swing.JProgressBar)e.getSource();
        if(bar.getValue() == 100)
            text2.setText("You dit it");
});
```